# How to create in Django a table with unique ID that increments on duplicate keys

Tags: mysql, django

I'm kind of new to Django and I've hit a bit of a wall with building out the project.

Essentially, I have two tables. Projects and Entries. Users create projects, then add entries to each project. Entries has an auto_increment ID, and a column for project_Id to specify which project owns the entries, but the entry ID increments site-wide. I would like to have entries increment on a per-project basis, so that the first Entry a user creates in their Project will always be 1, and the 2nd Entry will be 2, etc.

Can I do this in models.py? For example, in:

```
class Entries(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
```

can I create another line (say, entry_unique) that will tell it to create another column that increments +1 when project_id and entry_unique are the same as a previous table entry?

It's very important that each entry gets a visible (to user) entry ID # that increments +1 each time they create a new entry for that project, and that they be able to navigate through their entries by going +1 or -1 via "forward" and "backward" URLs.

Comment: do you have a `date_created` field in the `Entries` model ?

Comment: yes, there's a date_published that uses timezone to put in the exact time

Comment: Then you can override the `save` method of the model to save the unique entry for the `(user, project)` combination

Answer (score 1):

You can override the model `Entry`'s `save` method to accomplish what you want to do:

```
class Entries(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        project = kwargs.pop('project')

        latest = Entries.objects.filter(user=request.user, project_id=project)
        latest_entry = latest.entry_unique if latest else 1         
        self.entry_unique = latest_entry

        super(Entries, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, wherever you reference the project id, for a user, you can reference `entry.entry_unique`

Read up about [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#get-latest-by) here

Comment: I tried to do it that way but I didn't have any luck. I put this into views: latest = Entries.objects.latest('project_id') &     latest_entry = latest.entry_unique if latest else 0 but it is only incrementing the entry_unique once every two entries is created. Am I extracting the number of objects and not the value of the object?

Comment: I recommend to do it in the models' save and not the view

Comment: It didn't wind up working, but it gave me enough to work with, I wound up adding this into views: `if Entries.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).exists():
  mostrecententry = Entries.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).order_by('-entry_pubdate')[0]
  newentrynumber = mostrecententry.entry_unique if mostrecententr` which works. Now I'm trying to get it to deploy. Thanks for the help! Sorry I forgot to respond